# How to set an item with position absolute at the exact location everytime CSS

Tags: css

I have a Grid template and I am using a countdown timer with React, that returns how many seconds are left. Unfortunately, I need to use it in a different child div, because there is a function I am using. I can edit it but it would take lots of refactoring and testing everything again, so I would prefer not to.

Here is my .css code:

```
    .countdown{
        position: absolute;
        top: 11.4%;
        left: 70.4%;
        font-size: 14px;
        color: red;  
    }
```

When the screen is smaller, it is positioned as I want to but as the width gets bigger, the element goes more to the left (so it doesn't work with percentage). And the problem is that if I want a media-query it would take almost every single width resolution option. So is there another way to position the element with the absolute attribute and it doesn't get too much moved from its position in the different resolution?

Comment: Put your HTML and CSS together in a code snippet so we can visualize the issue. There's no way to tell with just that one css selector.

Comment: Your container is positioned related to the nearest parent container with position different than `static`. Maybe you should find the best parent container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your parent width and height was set with `viewport` sizes `vh,vw` It would be at the same position in any device. because the parent is responsive and we are your using percentage which means it always be `70%` from the `left`. if the screen size is `100px` it will be `70px` from the left & screen size is `1000px` it will be `700px` from the left. I hope it makes sense.

```css
.countdown {
  position: absolute;
  top: 11.4%;
  left: 70.4%;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: red;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

.parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 80vw;
  height: 80vh;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="countdown">
    09:00
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use pixels instead of percentages for your top and left values.